# Code example for dealing with 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'

Tags: html, iframe

I am trying to embed a webpage in an iFrame and it gives the below error..

```
Refused to display 'http://somewebsit.com'' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'.
```

I know this question has been addressed in [other posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6666423/overcoming-display-forbidden-by-x-frame-options#answer-7469997) but I could not find a code sample of what exactly I need to add to my HTML to get around it. For example what should exactly should I put next to my link in the code below...

```
<iframe width="854" height="510" src="http://somewebsit.com" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

If it is something like &output=embed as suggested in the other form posts, I am not sure where exactly it goes.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You **can't** put anything in your HTML to get around it. That would defeat the entire object of having it in the first place.

If you want to display the page in a frame, then the server sending that page must not limit the frame to the same origin. i.e. it should not set the header.

Sticking `&output=embed` on the end of the URL to turn it off (which would require you to control `somewebsit.com`) would be pointless, since anyone could use that URL instead of the version without the query string.

You could use something like `&embed=example.com` on the URL, then `somewebsit.com` (so this still requires that you control `somewebsit.com`) could examine that header, check `example.com` against a whitelist of sites that are allowed to embed the page, then set `X-Frame-Options: ALLOW-FROM example.com`, but browser support for that is currently pretty poor.

Comment: So are you saying there is no way for me to have that page in an iFrame unless I control it? Why then were suggestions offered in the post that I linked to?

Comment: Because Google Maps has already done the security unlock. Presumably they serve a different (cut down) version of the page for third party embeds.